# Set Lockscreen in Windows 8 through Flip View Control

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a collection of Images coded inline in my Flipview Control for a Windows 8 Application.

At the click of a button, I want the user to be able to set the `flipview.selecteditem` as lockscreen.

Can you help with a code snippet ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  Please post some code to show where you are having trouble.  If you have no code to show, try searching for the information first before asking us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [lock screen personalization sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147) and let us know if you have any specific questions, along with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Paul., I did check it. It discusses about opening an image from library and then setting it as lockscreen. Now the challenge is I have a collection of images in my assets folder and I do not know to map my image as a storage file. If I'm able to treat my image file as a storage then am good to go... Any idea ???

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the docs for file access: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx . Check the info under the "Application install directory" heading. There is also a sample for that, as well: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597 . Follow those and you should not have any trouble getting your images from your application package.

Comment: Paul.., I guess I'll get through with the cited example ... Thanks million